# Problem with momentum values in a QM problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, probability, discrete

I have the following equation of $Ψ$ around a ring (the particle is bound to move only on the ring):
[image]

To visualize the state(it dies before L/2 if L=2πR):
[image]

We can see from the first picture that from trying to find the probability for each $p$ to be measured,we find $A_p$ to be a continuous function of $p$. So here is my problem. If you analyze this problem, you find that momentum can only have some particular discrete values(because $Ψ(x+L)=Ψ(x)$ ) while the Ap(p) is a continuous function of p, meaning that it gives us probability for every p.  Also, because the probability is (Ap)^2 then we also have probability for the values that p can not have, so if you sum up each probability of each discrete value that p can take, then it will not be equal to 1.

So,what is going on? Did i misinterpreted something about the values of the momentum?

Comment: If your position space is a circle with radius $R$, then why would you integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in the integral?

Comment: As it is explained in the solution of this problem, it does not matter because the function Ψ(x) dies long before L/2,so the integral outside L/2(before that to be precise) will be equal to zero. In his lectures, he does the same thing as his notes(this is from his notes) but he integrate from -L/2 to L/2 and he gets the same answer. He is Shankar by the way(maybe you have watched his lectures or got his book).

Comment: Link to lectures/notes? page?

Comment: Your function isn't even well-defined on a circle, because $\psi(x) \neq \psi(x + 2\pi R)$ regardless of $R$. It is a general fact that periodic functions are expandable in discrete [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series), and your problem is precisely that your function isn't periodic because it is periodicity that leads to discrete momenta.

Comment: @Qmechanic a link to the video lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE4MnuhMtb4

Comment: @ACuriousMind this is what bothers me too.The function gives rise to continuous values for the momentum while the lecturer(in the link i have put above) showed that in this circle you can only have discrete values of p(as a first example). Then as a second exaple he wrote down this function and set out to find Ap(p). And it got me really confused

Comment: Can you include your discrete values of $p$? If they are discrete and can be expressed in terms of an integer $n$ then that automatically limits the $A_p$s...

Comment: @danimal its exactly the way you are saying it.The values of p vary only by the integer n. The lecturer himself told that the momentum here comes in discrete values and then went on and gave this equation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind this function does not follow ψ(x)=ψ(x+2πR) but its ok to have it as a superposition of the states of definite momentum. The problem here is why is Ap(p) continuous

Comment: It's not really continuous because when you put the $p$ values in it becomes dependant just on $n$

Comment: At the end of his lecture(the link i have put in the comments) he goes on and draws the graph of Ap(p). I thought of what you are saying, but if the continuous graph gives us the whole probability(1 if normalized) when integrated, then if you only take the probabilities of the discrete values they won't add up to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, realize we are doing an *approximation* when we are evaluating the coefficient $A_p$ in the Fourier series
$$ \psi(x) = \sum_p A_p \psi_p(x)$$
by the integral
$$ A_p = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi_p^*(x)\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
since the limits should really be the boundary of the interval on which the Fourier series is periodic. Furthermore, $\psi(x) = \sqrt{\alpha}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha\lvert x \rvert}$ is *not* an actual proper wavefunction on a circle of length $L$, since it is not periodic (but the function
$$ \phi(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-\alpha \lvert (x \mod L) \rvert}$$
would be, so if $\alpha \gg L$, we do not really make an error here, since its integral outside $[-L/2,L/2]$ then approximately vanishes). So the $A_p$ calculated like this should be a good approximation for the precise coefficent of the Fourier series if we plug in the allowed values for the momenta and just forget about the rest.

As you note in a comment, the coefficients obtained by this do not, at a first glance, sum to one if only summed over the discrete values. However, the [integral test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) provides the following bound:
$$ \int_N^\infty f(x)\mathrm{d}x \le \sum_{i = N}^\infty f(i) \le f(N) + \int_N^\infty f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
and if we let $N\to-\infty$, then $\lim_{N\to-\infty} A_N = 0$, and the sum over all coefficients is bounded below and above by the integral, so if the integral is $1$, the sum also is.

Comment: I did not properly understand your last statements about the problem with the coefficients..

Comment: Also, given Ap(p) (from my question), how can i integrate to find the probability of finding a momentum po? Because it comes in discrete quantities, i think that i can not use the integral of the probability density Ap to find the probability for each value. So what must i do to calculate each probability?

Comment: @LandosAdam: Suppose $\int_{-\infty}^\infty A_p \mathrm{d} p = 1$ and $\lim_{p\to-\infty}A_p = 0$ as in your example. Then, the bounds yield $1 \le \sum_{p = -\infty}^{\infty}A_p \le 1$, so $\sum_{p = -\infty}^{\infty}A_p = 1$. And since the momenta are discrete, you do not have to integrate - $\lvert A_p \rvert^2$ is the probability to find $\psi$ in the state $\psi_p$.

Comment: So if i plug in all the allowed momenta in Ap and i come up with all the Ap's and sum them,i will automatically get 1?

Comment: @LandosAdam: Yes, up to some error incurred by the approximation (note that, for example, the integral test supposes a decreasing series, so it is not immediately applicable. One can however modify my argument slightly and apply the test for $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty A_n$ in $A_0 + 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty A_n$ to get that it is at least close to $1$.)

Comment: Can't that error be very big in some problems?

Comment: @LandosAdam: That's the case with every approximation - you will find cases where it breaks down. In this case, the error is small when $\alpha \gg L$, so it is the same approximation again. Really, you are massively overthinking this silly approximation, in my opinion.

Comment: i wanted to ask you something else.Does the momentum/energy always have to be quantized?For example,a free particle does not have any restrictions(not living in a circle and things like that,just free in a one dimensional space with x being between minus infinity and plus infinity)